# Pagination 1st page link in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

i have this problem where in the 1st page has no link like base_url/controller/function/page_number.. please see the screenshot below

[image]

but when i inspected the element on the "1" page i only see this link

[image]

now my problem is that while all other links has a page number, why does "1" doesn't have one, it will mess up my routes.

Here is my config for the pagination..

My controller

```
public function testaccounts($params = FALSE)
{

    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->library('table');

    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'accounts/test';
    $config['total_rows'] = 200;
    $config['per_page'] = 5;
    $config['num_links'] = 20;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $this->load->view('testaccounts');
}
```

and my view contains only create_link() function to display the pagination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding:

```
$config['first_url'] = '1';
```

Should fix it so it doesn't have the link to `test/` for page one, rather it will force it to go to `test/1`

Comment: yes yes it fixed the problem... but how come it wasn't mentioned on its user guide.. and most of the guides i've read don't have it either.. and theirs just worked fine.. hmmm i don't get it :D

Comment: I'm not sure.  I knew about it by reading the pagination class before and knowing if you extend it, you can modify that first value with `$this->first_url`, also saw it in a forum before, but don't know where.  Little known and obscure.  Though, for the most part, not including the `/1` wouldn't cause it to break the routes. ^^

Comment: i see.. hmm maybe in my case it would break my routing.. i have this routing just to clean up the urls :D